# Different select result for exists ?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am scratching my head to figure out why these two delete results are different in sqlite3.

The problem is "If two students A and B are friends, and A likes B but not vice-versa, remove the Likes tuple. " from [here](https://class.stanford.edu/courses/DB/SQL/SelfPaced/courseware/ch-sql/seq-exercise-sql_social_mod/), Q2. (along with the [actual data](https://class.stanford.edu/c4x/DB/SQL/asset/socialdata.html))

The schema for `Friend` and `Likes` are

```
.schema Friend
CREATE TABLE Friend(ID1 int, ID2 int);
```

and

```
.schema Likes
CREATE TABLE Friend(ID1 int, ID2 int);
```

The two solutions I have come up with are:

```
-- This is correct
delete from Likes where not exists 
     (select 1 from Likes as l2 where l2.ID1=Likes.ID2 and l2.ID2=Likes.ID1) 
and exists 
     (select 1 from Friend where Likes.ID1=Friend.ID1 and Likes.ID2=Friend.ID2);
```

and

```
-- Combinng two select into one but this is incorrect
delete from Likes where not exists 
     (select 1 from Likes as l2, Friend as f where 
      l2.ID1=Likes.ID2 and l2.ID2=Likes.ID1 and 
      Likes.ID1=f.ID1 and Likes.ID2=f.ID2);
```

You see, the only difference is I combined two selects into one.

The incorrect version is wrong because the tuple (1782, 1709) is incorrectly deleted, but it should not because this tuple is not in `Friend`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the correct query, the first subquery uses NOT EXISTS, while the second one uses EXISTS.
Combining them does not make sense because the meaning of the existence of a matching `Friend` row is negated.